# Python list of lists- access to individual elements

Tags: python, data-structures

I am trying to access a particular element of a list of lists in Python. I am bringing a bit of C/Java baggage and thinking of this data structure as a 2D array. In my mind, the operation below should affect the first item of the first list only, `loc1[0][0]` in Java speak. In practice, the first item of each sublist is affected, i.e. `loc1[0][0]`, `loc1[1][0]` and `loc1[2][0]`. Any idea why that is?

```
def move(loc, dir, nrows, ncols):
  loc1 = [[0.0] * ncols] * nrows

  for col in range(1):
      for row in range(1):
          loc1[row][col] += 100.0 * loc[row][col]

  return loc1
nrows = 4
ncols = 3
p = [[1.0 / (ncols * nrows)] * ncols] * nrows #uniform prior

print p
p = move(p, [0, 1], nrows, ncols)
print p
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Comment: We have probably dozens of effective duplicates of this question, but I don't know how to search for them effectively :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had this happen before and it's frustrating.

Your problem is this line of code, which isn't doing what you think it is:

```
loc1 = [[0.0] * ncols] * nrows
```

`[0.0] * ncols` creates a single list which is passed by reference to form your 2D list.

Try this:

```
loc1 = [[0.0 for y in range(ncols)] for x in range(nrows)]
```

Comment: I sometime wonder who designed this. Thank you, it work, will accept in 7 minutes.

Comment: @reseter: anything and everything is "passed by reference" in Python. [There are no variables only names](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables). Imagine `[x]*n` would copy `x` item `n` times. How do you define a copy operation on an arbitrary object? Is it shallow/deep copy? Do you restrict the operation only to "pickleable" objects?

Answer (score 3):

`[x]*n` produces a list that contains the exact same `x` element `n` times.

`L = [0.0] * ncols` works because `0.0` is a float and floats are immutable in Python therefore `L[0] += 1.1` doesn't change `0.0` but places `1.1` in its place.

Lists are mutable therefore when you change any row in `L = [[0]*ncol]*nrow` you change all of them because it is the same object.

To fix it you could:

```
L = [[0.0]*ncols for _ in xrange(nrows)]
```

It creates a *new* list for each row so you can change them independently.

Or:

```
from itertools import repeat

L = [[0.0]*ncols for _ in repeat(None, nrows)]
```

Whatever is more readable for you.